# Can someone prove (or disprove) this assertion about the normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, proof

Let $X$ be distributed as a $Normal (\mu, \sigma^2)$. Then for a fixed $\mu$ it is always the case that:

\begin{equation}
\frac{90th quantile-10th quantile}{\sigma}=constant \quad \forall \sigma>0
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this "too trivial"? @Bob Jansen

Comment: First of all, it’s a stats question and not a quantitative finance question. Second, it follows from the definition as shown by @KeSchn. Third, you should show your own attempts at answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p\in(0,1)$. The [corresponding quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Quantile_function) of $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is given by $$F_X^{-1}(p)=\mu+\sigma\Phi^{-1}(p)=\mu+\sqrt{2}\sigma\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(2p-1),$$
where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function of a standard normally distributed random variable and $\mathrm{erf}^{-1}$ is the inverted error function.

Thus,
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{Quantile}(0.9)-\mathrm{Quantile}(0.1)}{\sigma}&=\frac{\mu+\sigma\Phi^{-1}(0.9)-(\mu+\sigma\Phi^{-1}(0.1))}{\sigma}  \\
&=\Phi^{-1}(0.9)-\Phi^{-1}(0.1) \\
&\approx 2.56.
\end{align}

Comment: Impeccable, thanks!